# Apache Solr Search API default result filters

Tags: apache, search, indexing, solr, nutch

I'm using Solr with apache nutch to indexing website

My json result looks like this:

```
  "response": {
"numFound": 0,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "http://mysite.pl/cl-BR/link/link",
    "url": "http://mysite.pl/cl-BR/link/link",
    "content": [
      "content"
    ],
    "_version_": 0000
  },
  {
    "id": "http://mysite.pl/ru-RU/link/link",
    "url": "http://mysite.pl/ru-RU/link/link",
    "content": [
      "content"
    ],
    "_version_": 0000
  },
  {
    "id": "http://mysite.pl/en-EN/link/link",
    "url": "http://mysite.pl/en-EN/link/link",
    "content": [
      "content"
    ],
    "_version_": 0000
  },
```

I would like to add parameter to my query, contains information about language into format for example like this: `en-EN`
And next return only search result where url contains my parameter.

For example:
My query is: `/solr/CoreName/select?q=you&fl=id,ul,content&urlContains=en-EN`

My result is:

```
  "response": {
"numFound": 0,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "http://mysite.pl/en-EN/link/link",
    "url": "http://mysite.pl/en-EN/link/link",
    "content": [
      "content"
    ],
    "_version_": 0000
  },
```

And when my query is: `/solr/CoreName/select?q=you&fl=id,ul,content&urlContains=ru-RU`

My result is:

```
  "response": {
"numFound": 0,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "http://mysite.pl/ru-RU/link/link",
    "url": "http://mysite.pl/ru-RU/link/link",
    "content": [
      "content"
    ],
    "_version_": 0000
  },
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *cleanest* implementation would be to [add a custom field](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields) in your schema, and then [use `copyField` to copy](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields) the content from `url` to a `url_tokenized` field.

```
<copyField source="url" dest="url_tokenized" />
```

By [using a PatternTokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-RegularExpressionPatternTokenizer) you can tell Solr to split tokens by `/`, so that you get `ru-RU` as a token in the `url_tokenized` field:

```
<analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="/"/>
</analyzer>
```

Which should give you something like:

```
<fieldType name="url_tokenized" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="/"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

By adding the LowerCaseFilterFactory we'll make sure that ru-RU and ru-ru both are found regardless of casing used.

Querying would then be done by applying a filter query (`fq`) to the query string:

```
...&fq=url_tokenized:ru-ru
```

This will limit the response to documents that contains "/ru-ru/" somewhere in its URL.